# Consolidate value of a cell onto another in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a sheet I'm working on that I have a buying list and a net worth control.
Every time something from the list is marked as bought and it's buy out price is set, it adds the value to a expenditures sheet and subtracts from the buying list.
On the net worth control sheet I intend to do a monthly control to know how much was bought until a certain date.

Columns C to N are 1 column for each month of the year. Line 30 has the total net worth value (calculated through a formula summing the already bought items plus liquid income from investments).
On line 31 I want to consolidate these values as to have a journal of progress of net worth increase.

On C31, if TODAY is the first day of the month, I need it to copy the value of C30 (not the formula) and if it's not the first day of the month, *do nothing*.

I got to this formula:

> =IF(TODAY()=DATE.VALUE("01/01/2017");C30;"")

ps: this syntax works on brazillian portuguese Excel.

This formula checks if today is the first of January, 2017. Alright. If it is, it copies the content of C30. If not, it blanks C31.

I need to correct this formula to copy the result of C30 formula, not the formula itself. I also need a way to state "do nothing" on the false case in the IF().

Comment: So You can use Date.Value(Date(Year(Now());Month(Now());1). by using ;C30: You in fact reference to the value of C30 so I do not what You want to change. You can always change it to VALUE(C30) but it does not make a huge difference. And if I understand You correctly so when IF statement is false then You want to put 'do nothing' as a result of check? so then You can put ;C30;"do nothing")

Comment: pnuts, I believe my question falls into the category "software algorithm" is it's an algorithm I'm asking about (formula) of a software (Excel). Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: Mikisz, VALUE just converts from text to number. C30 is a calculation, which gives a result. I need to copy the result to C31 without copying the formula, so IF I change the numbers of the formula later I will not change the value in C31. It's a consolidation cell.

Comment: pnuts, I'm using Brazillian portuguese Excel 2007. Formulae from C30 is =(C28)+C29+SOMASE('Lista de Compras'!$I$4:$I$87;"verde";'Lista de Compras'!$K$4:$K$87) . Formulae for C31 is =SE(HOJE()<=DATA.VALOR("29/06/2017");C30;""). I need this =SE (=IF) to do nothing in case it's false.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Line 30 is a calculation, with one column for each month. January is C30, February is D30 and so on.
Line 31 is a consolidation, with one column to consolidate each month. So C31 registers the value until the last day of January, D31 registers the value until the last day of February and so on.

I needed line 31 to copy the result of the calculation in line 30, so I can later track the progress of the value increase throughout the year.

Suppose the value of C30 is =SUM(Z1:Z30). Values in Z column will change from time to time. Values that were changed during the month of January should be registered (consolidated) in C31 until right before the first of February. After we reach February the value of C31 should not change anymore, doesn't matter how much I change the values in Z column.

My final formula for C31 is:

> =SE(HOJE()<=DATA.VALOR("31/01/2017");C30;C31)

Portuguese Function - English Function
SE(teste;verdadeiro;falso): IF(test,true,false) function
HOJE(): TODAY() function
DATA.VALOR(): DATE.VALUE() function

IF checks TODAY() against a fixed date, in my case, the last day of the month. To make the check work, as TODAY() gets the date in serial, I need to turn the date I wrote as limit to serial as well and that is done through DATE.VALUE().
If today is still in the month of January (that is, earlier than the last day of the month, including the last day), it gets the value of C30.
After that, first of February onward, it will reference *itself*. I had to allow Excel to do recursive calculation in Calculation Options, of course, for that to work.
Tested it altering the date of my computer and changing the values, it worked as intended.

Thanks guys!